# Error installing v8js on windows xampp server

Tags: php, xampp, v8

I'm trying to install v8js on my windows xampp server.

I've followed the instructions in this tutorial:
https://blog.xenokore.com/how-to-install-v8js-for-php-on-windows/

However when i try and run `php I get:

```
C:\Users\paul>php -v
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_v8js.dll' - The specified procedure could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_v8js.dll' - The specified procedure could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP 7.1.1 (cli) (built: Jan 18 2017 18:51:14) ( ZTS MSVC14 (Visual C++ 2015) x86 )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.5.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2017, by Derick Rethans
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also need to copy the three "extra" dlls into apache\bin

- v8.dll
- icui18n.dll
- icuuc.dll

You'll need them in \php\ for running PHP as command line, or \apache\bin\ for running under apache.